# When element clicked append to div, if clicked again remove from that div and return it to exact position it came from

Tags: jquery, html

When element is click append element to div specified, if clicked again remove that element from that div then return it to the exact position it came from. I know my current code does not have it so the jQuery I have is a) a work-around but more importantly b) does not work. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the guidance.

```js
$('.choices').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (($this.attr('id') == '#translateBoxCover')) {
    $this.remove().appendTo('#choicesWrapper');
  } else {
    $this.appendTo("#translateBoxCover");
  }
});
```

```css
#translateBoxWrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#translateBox {
  width: 70%;
  height: 175px;
  border: 5px dashed white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.translateBoxCover {
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  margin: 1% auto;
}

#choices {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#choicesWrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.choices {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.50);
  border-radius: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='translateBoxWrapper'>
  <div id='translateBox'>
    <div id='translateBoxCover'> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='choices'>
  <div id='choicesWrapper'>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>中国</div>
    <div class='choices'>美国</div>
    <div class='choices'>爱</div>
    <div class='choices'>喜欢</div>
    <div class='choices'>我</div>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>他</div>
    <div class='choices'>川普</div>
    <div class='choices'>厕所</div>
    <div class='choices'>想</div>
    <div class='choices'>你</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$this.attr('id') == '#translateBoxCover'` will never be true. Did you mean `$this.parent().attr('id')`?

Comment: @Barmar that and it looks like the `id` RHS was interpreted as a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the index before you move the element. You can use `.data()` to save information in the element.

Also, the ID doesn't include the `#` character, that's just the selector syntax for it.

And you don't need to use `.remove()` when you're moving an element. An element can only be in one place in the DOM, so appending it to a new place will automatically remove it from the old place.

```js
$('.choices').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.parent().attr('id') == 'translateBoxCover') {
    var index = $this.data('index');
    if (index == 0) {
      $this.prependTo($("#choicesWrapper"));
    } else {
      $this.insertAfter($("#choicesWrapper .choices").eq(index-1));
    }
  } else {
    $this.data('index', $this.index());
    $this.appendTo("#translateBoxCover");
  }
});
```

```css
#translateBoxWrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#translateBox {
  width: 70%;
  height: 175px;
  border: 5px dashed white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.translateBoxCover {
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  margin: 1% auto;
}

#choices {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#choicesWrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.choices {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.50);
  border-radius: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='translateBoxWrapper'>
  <div id='translateBox'>
    <div id='translateBoxCover'> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='choices'>
  <div id='choicesWrapper'>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>中国</div>
    <div class='choices'>美国</div>
    <div class='choices'>爱</div>
    <div class='choices'>喜欢</div>
    <div class='choices'>我</div>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>很</div>
    <div class='choices'>他</div>
    <div class='choices'>川普</div>
    <div class='choices'>厕所</div>
    <div class='choices'>想</div>
    <div class='choices'>你</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, appreciate the help. Have a few follow up questions. For 'if ($this.parent().attr('id') == 'translateBoxCover')', can you explain why translateBoxCover is the parent of .choices? I thought the parent of .choices is div with id choicesWrapper?

Comment: Ah, answered my own question.